# JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of

Tags: android

I had a PHP API which showed a JSON Array, which I then read into an Android Application.

I since moved servers and the android application broke.

I assumed it was the Authentication and thought I would re-build the Android application (Was my first application and thought a re-write could make things better)

For some reason I am now getting this exception error

I read somewhere that I need to parse JSON_FORCE_OBJECT in the PHP json_encode

```
json_encode($arrMyData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

But I am running PHP 5.2 (Options parameter came out in PHP 5.3)

My code for you to rip into

```
private void displayAllStories(){

    String line;
    int intNumStories       = 0;
    JSONObject arrAllStories;
    LinearLayout storiesLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyoutStoriesMain);
    storiesLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    try {

        while((line = this.jsonResult.readLine()) != null){
            JSONObject arrStories;
            arrStories              = new JSONObject(line.trim());
            intNumStories           = Integer.parseInt(arrStories.optString("NumStories"));
            arrAllStories           = arrStories.getJSONObject("StoryData");

            this.strDebug += "We have "+intNumStories+"\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.strDebug += "Error (3) "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n";
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        this.strDebug += "Error (4) "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n";
    }
}
```

And the encoded data from the website

```
{
   "NumStories":1,
   "StoryData":{
      "Story0":{
         "ID":"1020",
         "OWERNAME":"Alicia",
         "STORYMAIN":"Good evening my son was born with bilateral club feet. When he was a week old we started serial casting once a week for 3 months and then he was placed in braces for the next 6 months for a 23 hour period and then for the next 3 months just durning the night. This last visit the doctor said that he needs to have his tendons lengthened and he will go back into cast. After reading all of these articles I am a little scared on what will be best for him. It sounds like the risk of having the surgery are just as heavily weighed as just keeping him in AFO\\'s till he can make his own decision. I would like all advice whether it be positive or negative. Thank you in advance for your help.",
         "STORYBRIEF":"Need reassurance that tendon lengthening is the best decision.",
         "ADDEDDATE":"2011-12-12 00:51:16",
         "CURRENTSTATUS":"n"
      }
   }
}
```

Sorry I should add, the code before this which procudes jsonResult is as follows

```
 try{
            URL url                     = null;
            URLConnection urlConn       = null;
            InputStreamReader jsonIsr   = null;
            BufferedReader jsonBr       = null;

            //this.strDebug += "URL is "+this.strURL+"\n";
            url = new URL(this.strURL);

            urlConn = url.openConnection();

            jsonIsr = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());

            jsonBr = new BufferedReader(jsonIsr, 8192);

            this.jsonResult = jsonBr;

            return true;


        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            this.strDebug += "JSON Error (1) "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n";
        }catch(IOException e){
            this.strDebug += "JSON Error (2) "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n";
        }
    }else{
        strDebug = "NO URL Passed to JSON\n";
    }
```

// EDIT 2

For those who asking

The error is as the title says

```
 Error (4) A JSONObject text must being with '{' at character 1 of {"NumStories":1, "StoryData":........
```

Comment: If your array is associative (which it seems to be), you don't need the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` argument. Only if you want to convert numerical array into an object. And what is the problem you actually have? It's not clear.

Comment: what the jsonResult was actually contain?

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes that whole JSON data comes on one line: it iterates with `readLine()` but creates a new JSON object every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the data line by line and trying to convert each line into a JSON object. That won't work because a single line just contains a fragment of a complete JSON object.

I don't know what type `jsonResult` has. But you'll probably want to read the whole thing at once.

Your old web application probably produced JSON data without line break so a single line would contain a full JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

i think you read the json file line by line and pass to the json object you should like this way the whole string you have to pass to the json object for parsing than only you getting the json

```
JSONObject arrStories = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
```

now get the object like this way

```
intNumStories = Integer.parseInt(arrStories.getString("NumStories"));
```

Comment: arrStories in a jsonObject (written the line above) but currently intNumStories is not even working, its falling on the IOException

Comment: try to get this id like this way into the integer and print it arrStories.getJsonObject("StoryData").getJsonObject("Story0").getString("ID");

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to break, if object takes more than one line (apparemtly it does). Your choices are:

- Collect all the strings into string builder, the parse from this string ( http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html )
- Take  GSON or my databinding layer ( https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer )   and just parse stream into object.

Comment: Once I get the value intNumStories I will set a loop on that figure to loop through arrAllStories, which in return will give me individual stories.

Comment: Judging from this point of view , your best solution would be to use pull parser like GSON  and databinding on top ( see the link - there are unit tests ).   build in JSON parser is very puoor in terms of memory utilisation.